# R - rm() objects in loop

Tags: r, list, loops

I want to be able to remove objects in a loop dependent on `i`; for example I have objects called `A1, A2, A3, A4, ..., A999, A1000`. What I want is something like:

```
for(i in 1:1000){
  rm(paste0("A", i))
}
```

I know that this just pastes `A1`, `A2`, etc., as text, but I don't know where to go from here to convert that text to an object.

I have tried using `get` and `lapply`, but I am clearly doing this wrong.

Comment: `rm(list=paste0("A", 1:1000))`

Comment: Thanks @jogo, sorted out my problem straight away. Slightly modified it as I needed to use each Ai in the loop, so now it just removes it as it goes. Again, Many thanks!!! rm(list=paste0("A",i))

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i in 1:1000){
rm(list=paste0("A",i))
}
```

This lists `i`  for `1:1000` and removes them from the Environment

Comment: Code-only answers are often unhelpful in pointing to why the issue happened. Please include an explanation for why your code solves the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)